# How to use SoapUI plugin for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to "SoapUI IntelliJ Plugin", and I have just installed the latest SoapUI IntelliJ Plugin:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7485-soapui-intellij-plugin

but I cannot find any guide on how to use the plugin with IntelliJ.
(There is only one video guide on youtube for eclipse plugin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAytFBS1ZG0). However, since IntelliJ does not have the same "layout" as eclipse does (for example: eclipse seems provide a SoupUI view after installing the plugin. Whereas I could not find the equivalence in IntelliJ)

My intelliJ version is: Ultimate 2017.3

can somebody who has experience with this shed some light?

thanks,

Comment: From the link you installed from: "Tools -> SoapUI" Have you tried this?

Comment: thanks @DavidPostill, you are right. I overlooked that.

The following steps worked for me:
1. click "Tools -> SoapUI -> start soapui"
2. then a "soapUI NMavigator" view tab appears.